# FlatMap after splitting RDD file in one spark command

Tags: apache-spark

I cannot find my mistake here. I want to split the file by comma and then mount a tuple in one command. I searched on Stack Overflow, but most of the answer divide in more than one command.

```
val testRDD = myFile.flatMap(x => { val str = x.split(',') ( str( 0 ) , ( str( 2 ).toInt , str( 4 ).toInt) )}).collect()
```

And the file is:

```
1,testea,0,testeb,3
2,testea,0,testeb,0
3,testea,4,testeb,0
```

Comment: Why do you need `.flatMap`? I think if the only requirement is return a tuple based on each line, you can just replace `flatMap` by `.map`.  `val testRDD = myFile.map(x => { val str = x.split(','); ( str( 0 ) , ( str( 2 ).toInt , str( 4 ).toInt) )}).collect()`

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Why shouldn't I use flatmap? Since I want to reduce the data by iterating thought it I thought on flatMap, Is not this? Also, I tried with the change you suggested and I've got: "<console>:25: error: value split is not a member of Array[String]
"

Comment: There are a couple of points here. First one is the difference of `flatMap` vs `map`. Basically, you will iterate each item in your df or rdd, the difference is the return type, while `flatMap` will expect List/Seq/etc, `map` will expect a single item, in this case, your tuple; this is why you can use it for this scenario. Second point here is the datatype of `myFile`, you can add `myFile.as[String]` before the `map` to work with `split` within the `.map`.

Comment: Ok!! Now I got it, thanks!! Sorry to bother but just one thing, putting the cast it gives me and error that I think that it says to me that the 'as' operator is not imported. Tried to find how to do this but it says that is scala native, so should be already imported; Do you know something? "error: value as is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]
"

Comment: That's because `myFile` is an `RDD` and `.as` is for `DataFrames`. In this case, I think you don't event need the  `.split`. You need to verify the datatype of `myFile`, but I think you can use: `myFile.map(i=> (i._1, i._2.toInt, i._3, i._4.toInt)).collect()` and it will do the same.

Comment: Ok, if I do fromfile.collect() I got a Array[String]. But with this command you send I have "value _4 is not a member of String", "value _3 is not a member of String"...

Comment: And if I change to this "val a = fromfile.map(i=> (i(1), i(2).toInt, i(3), i(4).toInt)).collect()" I got this weird response of the collect: "Array((,,32,S,101), (,,32,S,101), (,,32,S,101))"

Comment: Can you please share how do you get the data for `myFile` ?

Comment: sure! 
val myFile = sc.textFile("/home/etc")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this input:

```
1,testea,0,testeb,3
2,testea,0,testeb,0
3,testea,4,testeb,0
```

There are few alternatives.

1 - Keeping your approach:

```scala
val yourFilePath: String = // Here your path value
val output = spark.sparkContext.textFile(yourFilePath).map(line=>{val array = line.split(","); (array(0), array(2).toInt, array(4).toInt)})
output

output.collect()

//output:
output: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int, Int)] = MapPartitionsRDD[4] at map at <console>:18
res2: Array[(String, Int, Int)] = Array((1,0,3), (2,0,0), (3,4,0))
```

2 - Read it directly with `.csv`:

```scala
spark.read.csv(yourFilePath).select("_c0", "_c2", "_c4").show()

//output:
+---+---+---+
|_c0|_c2|_c4|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  0|  3|
|  2|  0|  0|
|  3|  4|  0|
+---+---+---+
```